# Store navigation.title in variable iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can i grab the current view's navigation title and store it in a variable for use in my code?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
NSString *navTitle = self.navigationItem.title;
```